# Font-Awesome-Icons with Leaflet-Awesome-Markers not showing

Tags: jquery, css, leaflet, font-awesome

I'm sure it's something simple but I just don't see what I'm doing wrong. 
I'm using the Leaflet Awesome Markers plugin. The markers work great, the problem is that the Fontawesome-Icons are not visible. I've done everything step by step as told in the description, the following two lines are in my head-tag.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.awesome-markers.css">
```

these two lines are at the end of my html:

```
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="js/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
```

And as told in https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers here is my script:

```
var restaurantMarker = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
icon: 'coffee', 
markerColor: 'darkred',
prefix: 'fa', 
iconColor: 'black'
});

L.marker([48.185556, 11.620278], {icon: restaurantMarker}).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('Aumeister');
```

As it works here http://jsfiddle.net/VPzu4/92/ and at least I tried to do everything as it was described, I just don't see the fault....

[image: fontawesome-markers-leaflet]
Furthermore, as you can see in the picture the icon should be in the marker ...

Comment: Go to the network tab in the developer tools and reload the page, is the image loading? What error code does the image return? Are they errors in the console? Should the first `<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapc...` be `<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapc...`?

Comment: I've changed the link - still the same problem. there are no errors in the console.... really weird..

Comment: What does the network tab say when you open it, then refresh the page? It should give you a list of all the files downloaded. Do you see the 'font-awesome.min.css' file in that list? Was it successfully retrieved? Are you running this page locally or off of a server?

Comment: It says that the status is 304 - Not Modified

Comment: I'm running it from localhost

Comment: Can't imagine what the issue would be then. View the source of [this page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/VPzu4/92/show/) (from your jsfilddle) and compare it to your code on your local machine, and try to spot any differences or anything you might be missing.

Comment: Try moving the script files to the HEAD section instead of the end.

Comment: sorry, I don't see what it has to do with font-awsome-markers. When you try to get a tile, you have a nice 'Forbidden, wrong apikey' ... pretty clear message ... Am I missing something ?

Comment: hm? the problem was that the font-awesome icons were not visible. Everything was fine with the rest of my map. But it doesn't matter I got it work :) Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really can't help you completely since I don't have all the code **BUT**:

There seems to me that you don not use the right family for your Font-Awesome.
If you look at the font-family of your icon it says *"locate-fa"* and it gets the CSS from *locate-fa.css.22*.

I tested your code and it worked due to the correct CSS, [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VPzu4/293/).

```
.fa{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
```

However if you look at the CSS when you inspect the marker, it correctly says that the CSS is from *font-awesome.css* and that the font-family is the correct *FontAwesome*.

Try to find the "locate"-part that interfere with your CSS and it should work!

Comment: Thanks ;) And yes, you are completely right, I already noticed that, the locate-fa was the problem!

Comment: @user3671746 Awesome! Mark the answer as solved so others know that similar problems can be solved this way!